# React-bootstrap with Typescript: Using fill or justify prop causing typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

**Code**

```
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Tabs, Tab, Spinner, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { Categories } from '../../models/ICategory';
import IMovie from '../../models/IMovie';
import { getMovies } from '../../services/movies';
import Movies from '../Movies/index';


export default function Landing() {
    const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState<IMovie[]>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);

    const fetchFavourites = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const favourites = await getMovies(Categories.Favourite);
            setFavourites( favourites );
        } catch (error) {
            setError( error as Error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFavourites();
    }, [fetchFavourites]);

    if(loading) {
        return (
            <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
                <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </Spinner>
        )
    }

    if(!loading && error) {
        return (
            <Alert variant="danger">{error.message}</Alert>
        );
    }
    

    return (
        <Tabs
            defaultActiveKey={Categories.MoviesComing}
            id='landing-page-tab'
            className='mb-3 px-3'
            fill
        >
            <Tab eventKey={Categories.MoviesComing} title='Coming Soon'>
                <Movies category={Categories.MoviesComing} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={Categories.MoviesInTheaters} title='In Theatres'>
                <Movies category={Categories.MoviesInTheaters} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={Categories.TopRatedIndia} title='Top Rated In India'>
                <Movies category={Categories.TopRatedIndia} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={Categories.TopRatedMovies} title='Top Rated'>
                <Movies category={Categories.TopRatedMovies} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={Categories.Favourite} title='Favourites'>
                <Movies category={Categories.Favourite} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```

**Error**

> ERROR in src/components/Landing/index.tsx:50:13 TS2322: Type '{
> children: Element[]; defaultActiveKey: Categories; id: string;
> className: string; fill: true; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<TabsProps, "slot" | "style" | "title"
> | "variant" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" |
> "suppressContentEditableWarning" | ... 252 more ... |  Compiled with
> warnings.

Same happens when I add the justify prop to Tabs. The React-Bootstrap document suggests this method: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#fill-and-justify
And it works on webpage, but starts with an error and that compilation error.

*How can I include those props without the Typescript error?*

Answer (score 1):

Use @ts-ignore before the 'fill' attribute to disable the error for now. It will work. We have to open an issue on their Github repository to draw their attention to it.
Demonstration below:

```
<Tabs
   defaultActiveKey={Categories.MoviesComing}
   id='landing-page-tab'
   className='mb-3 px-3'
   // @ts-ignore
   fill
  >
     <Tab eventKey={Categories.MoviesComing} title='Coming Soon'>
            <Movies category={Categories.MoviesComing} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={Categories.MoviesInTheaters} title='In Theatres'>
            <Movies category={Categories.MoviesInTheaters} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={Categories.TopRatedIndia} title='Top Rated In India'>
            <Movies category={Categories.TopRatedIndia} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={Categories.TopRatedMovies} title='Top Rated'>
            <Movies category={Categories.TopRatedMovies} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={Categories.Favourite} title='Favourites'>
            <Movies category={Categories.Favourite} favourites={favourites} setFavourites={setFavourites} />
        </Tab>
  </Tabs
```